# Zero Accuracy for Deep Learning Model in Regression

Tags: python, deep-learning, regression, feature-extraction, resnet

I have a task for regression using deep learning. To this aim, I have used a ResNet50 model and added a few layers at the end for regression. In my problem, I have around 700 images that each image has a value associated with it. However, the problem here is that model accuracy during both training and validation is near zero. Can you please help what the problem might be?

**ResNet50 Model**

```
restnet = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=(224,224,3), pooling=None)
```

**Setting a Few Layers Trainable**

```
restnet.trainable = True
set_trainable = False
for layer in restnet.layers:
    if layer.name in ['conv5_block3_2_relu', 'conv5_block3_3_conv', 'conv5_block3_3_bn','conv5_block3_add','conv5_block3_out','res5c_branch2b','bn5c_branch2b']:
        set_trainable = True
    if set_trainable:
        layer.trainable = True
    else:
        layer.trainable = False
layers = [(layer, layer.name, layer.trainable) for layer in restnet.layers]
pd.DataFrame(layers, columns=['Layer Type', 'Layer Name', 'Layer Trainable'])
```

**Defining the shape of the last layer of the ResNet50:**

```
output = restnet.layers[-1].output
output = keras.layers.Flatten()(output)
restnet = Model(restnet.input, outputs=output)
for layer in restnet.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
output.shape
```

**Adding a few layers at the end for regression:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(restnet)
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_dim=(224,224,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Training process:**

```
history=model.fit(x=x_train, y = y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=200, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

As I mentioned, the accuracy for the model is near zero: (below screeshot). I have went through the training process (200 epochs) and the accuracy stays firm.

[Screenshot of the training/validation process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl47N.png)

The images have (224,224,3) shapes.

Comment: just for start - use less number of dense layers after resnet, & take it easy with the dropout...

Comment: Thanks @B.Kocis, I did so, and the same accuracy!

Comment: Also, do I need to do any kind of preprocessing on my images? Thanks